# Multiple columns listbox from array

Tags: excel, listbox, multiple-columns, vba

```
s="qweqe~drtd~edyte~rert`qw3eqe~drtd~edyt3e~rert`qw3eqe~drtd~3edyte~rert"

ListBoxArr = Split(Mid(s, 2), "`")
    For Li = LBound(ListBoxArr) To UBound(ListBoxArr)
        ListBoxArr2 = Split(ListBoxArr(Li), "~")
        For Ly = LBound(ListBoxArr2) To UBound(ListBoxArr2)
            With ListBox1
                .ColumnCount = 4
                .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50"
                   .AddItem
                   .List(Ly, 0) = ListBoxArr2(Ly)
                   .List(Ly, 1) = ListBoxArr2(Ly)
                   .List(Ly, 2) = ListBoxArr2(Ly)
                   .List(Ly, 3) = ListBoxArr2(Ly)
            End With
        Next Ly
    Next Li
```

I get error runtime error `380 Could not set the List property. Invalid property value` 
What is wrong? I need get 4 columns list box values from array

```
EMBED("Forms.ListBox.1";"")
```

debug on

```
.List(Ly, 1) = ListBoxArr2(Ly)
```

[image]

Comment: is it userform listbox? If yes, it works fine for me without any issue

Comment: try to change `With ListBox1` to  `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").ListBox1`

Comment: I dont thinks so and it not work! works only first .List(Ly, 0) = ListBoxArr2(Ly)

Answer (score 0):

One For/Next will do

In each revolution you split one set from 1st into 2nd dimension and immediately add a record to the box

Mind that the 1st column is already assigned during `.Add`

```
ListBox1.Clear  ' as a precaution to not double load
s = "qweqe~drtd~edyte~rert`qw3eqe~drtd~edyt3e~rert`qw3eqe~drtd~3edyte~rert"

ListBoxArr = Split(Mid(s, 2), "`")
For Li = LBound(ListBoxArr) To UBound(ListBoxArr)
    ListBoxArr2 = Split(ListBoxArr(Li), "~")

    With ListBox1

        .ColumnCount = 4
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50;50"

        .AddItem ListBoxArr2(0), Li
        .List(Li, 1) = ListBoxArr2(1)
        .List(Li, 2) = ListBoxArr2(2)
        .List(Li, 3) = ListBoxArr2(3)
    End With
Next Li
```

**reply to comment:**

Make sure you use an ActiveX object (not a Forms object); furthermore I have the following references (VBA window / menu: Tools / References); you may want to make sure you have them as well

[image]

Comment: runtime error "380" Could not set the List property. Invalid property value  on line .List(Li, 1) = ListBoxArr2(1)

Comment: i am using ActiveX object, all ref are enabled

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce your problem ... here XLS part of MS Office Prof Plus 2010 ... maybe you have an issue with wrong version or bad registration of MSCOMCTL.OCX ... see also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597986